# Trying to show a date as blank in a total row

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

SQL Server : when I select my totals row, for date I select ' ' but it gets converted to 1/1/1900 because it is a date column for all other rows.  What can i do to make it say blank.

I'm trying to show blank on a total line, on the detail line it's a date. On the total line it's 1/1/1900 so can be confusing. I would like to show blank on the total line.

Here is an example of my total row.  some of the blank values are  dates in the detail.

```
UNION ALL 
SELECT  TOP 99999999
AddUpdate
 , Members_SourceCode 
 ,  YearMonth  + ' Total Month' 
, ' ' 
, ' ' 
, ' ' 
, ' ' 
,  ' ' 
, ' ' 
, ' ' 
, ' ' 
, ' ' 
, ' ' 
, ' ' 
, ' ' 
, COUNT(Members_sourceCode) 

GROUP BY AddUpdate, Members_SourceCode, YearMonth
ORDER BY AddUpdate, Members_SourceCode, YearMonth
```

Comment: which database and what soruce code are you using

Comment: Date values in SQL either have a value or are `NULL`. _They cannot be blank/empty strings_, which is a different thing than `NULL`. But to provide more info than this about how to **show** a blank string to the user when the value is `NULL` we need to see more of your code and design.

Answer (score 0):

> `Nothing` represents the default value of a data type. The default value depends on whether the variable is of a value type or of a reference type.

[Nothing keyword (Visual Basic) - Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/nothing#remarks)

With VB.NET and EF 6.X to save null is:

```
Dim nullableData As New Nullable(Of Date)
```

Comment: you can save also DbNull.Value

Comment: Those are blank lines you can add manually instead of using a tables in VB.net.